# JMM and multithreaded communication with external devices and atomic variables

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

I have a piece of code running in a thread (hereafter called the "first thread") as follows:

```
myAtomicBoolean.set(true);
writeToSerial("foo");
```

And there is a second thread that is doing the following in a loop:

```
readSerialBlocking();
if(myAtomicBoolean.get()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

There is an external hardware setup that, when the first thread writes to its serial port, it will indirectly cause data to be sent to the serial port that the second thread uses. Because these are separate serial ports, the two threads *share no locks or monitors*. Their only shared information is that AtomicBoolean.

As I understand, a basic `get` and `set` for an AtomicBoolean [only touch an internal *volatile* variable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.java#AtomicBoolean.0value).

It is clear to me that the delay of the external hardware, OS, etc. will allow the variable set to propagate faster than the serial port will be available to read, but there is no sort of synchronization between the two threads that strictly guarantees such a behavior.

My graph-theory-fu is not sufficient to understand the [part of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) concerning thread requirements.

Is the program not properly synchronized in this case, or will the volatile write be guaranteed to propagate immediately to other threads (specifically, before `writeToSerial` is called?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "propagate". What the JMM guarantees is that `myAtomicBoolean.get()` will see the last value set by `myAtomicBoolean.set()`.

Comment: but you are calling readSerialBlocking before checking the variable. Only guessing, but typically you will not the read function before something is written to it.

Comment: Memory writes don't propagate to any thread. After the .set(true), any other thread will see "true". You might want to WriteToSerial before setting the Boolean to true. This way when the write completes, the other thread may then // do stuff.

Comment: @JBNizet When you say that `get` will see the last value set by `set`, is there an upper bound on how much later thread2 will see the volatile write of thread1? Obviously, it cannot happen within a single CPU cycle, but how much longer could it take in the absence of any synchronization across the two threads?

Comment: @Zielu The read function will read a response from a physical piece of hardware, that was triggered with the write from the other thread.

Comment: @hexafraction that's a bit too low-level for me, but let's just say that the value will be written to main memory by set() (and not to a local cache), and be read from the main memory by get() (and not from a local cache)